# .htaccess rewrite rewriting its own destination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a [website](https://bagelstat.us) that lets us know when bagels have arrived at the datacenters. It also has an API, with an .htaccess that worked perfectly until I upgraded Apache a week or so back, which broke some of my .htaccess rewrites. One of them is this:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !robots.txt
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ api.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Basically, it should rewrites `/anything` to `/api.php?key=anything`

This worked fine until I updated Apache, which broke it.
I am now on Apache/2.4.18. I turned up the verbosity of .htaccess logging and got this (I removed extraneous fields like timestamp and IP):

```
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/ ->
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] applying pattern '^([^/]*)/?$' to uri ''
[rewrite:trace4] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] RewriteCond: input='/home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/' pattern='!favicon.ico' => matched
[rewrite:trace4] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] RewriteCond: input='/home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/' pattern='!robots.txt' => matched
[rewrite:trace2] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] rewrite '' -> 'api.php?key='
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] split uri=api.php?key= -> uri=api.php, args=key=
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] add per-dir prefix: api.php -> /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/api.php
[rewrite:trace2] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] strip document_root prefix: /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/api.php -> /api.php
[rewrite:trace1] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2803e100/initial] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] internal redirect with /api.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2802f708/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] strip per-dir prefix: /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/api.php -> api.php
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2802f708/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] applying pattern '^([^/]*)/?$' to uri 'api.php'
[rewrite:trace4] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2802f708/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] RewriteCond: input='/home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/api.php' pattern='!favicon.ico' => matched
[rewrite:trace4] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2802f708/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] RewriteCond: input='/home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/api.php' pattern='!robots.txt' => matched
[rewrite:trace2] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2802f708/initial/redir#1] [perdir /home/bagelstatus/public_html/api/] rewrite 'api.php' -> 'api.php?key=api.php'
[rewrite:trace3] mod_rewrite.c(476): [api.bagelstat.us/sid#2817168][rid#7f2b2802f708/initial/redir#1] split uri=api.php?key=api.php ->  uri=api.php, args=key=api.php&key=
```

This happens over and over again until it errors out with

```
[core:error] [client limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

This did not happen previously. I found that I could partially fix it by adding

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !api.php
```

I'm not sure what my previous Apache version was, but it was some variant of 2.4. Here is my config:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar  5 2016 14:36:58
Cpanel::Easy::Apache v3.32.10 rev9999
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:52
Server loaded:  APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Compiled using: APR 1.5.2, APR-UTIL 1.5.4
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses disabled)
 -D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=256
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr/local/apache"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/local/apache/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="logs/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="conf/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="conf/httpd.conf"
```

Why is my .htaccess rule rewriting to itself (api.php) like this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use these conditions:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ api.php?key=$1 [L,QSA]
```